# Limiting data in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement the following with loading an internal data structure to pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(self.data, 
        nrows=num_rows+500,
        skiprows=skip_rows,
        header=header_row,
        usecols=limit_cols)
```

However, it doesn't appear to implement any of those (like it does when reading a `csv` file, other than the data). Is there another method I can use to have more control over the data that I'm ingesting? Or, do I need to rebuild the data before loading it into pandas?

My input data looks like this:

```
data = [

    ['ABC', 'es-419', 'US', 'Movie', 'Full Extract', 'PARIAH', '', '', 'EST', 'Features - EST', 'HD', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', 'Open', 'WSP', '10.5000', '', '', '', '', '10.5240/8847-7152-6775-8B59-ADE0-Y', '10.5240/FFE3-D036-A9A4-9E7A-D833-1', '', '', '', '04065', '', '', '2011', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '113811', '', '', '', '', '', '04065', '', 'Spanish (LAS)', 'US', '10', 'USA NATL SALE', '2017-05-11 00:00:00', 'TIER 3', '21', '', '', 'USA NATL SALE-SPANISH LANGUAGE', 'SPAN'],
    ['ABC', 'es-419', 'US', 'Movie', 'Full Extract', 'PATCH ADAMS', '', '', 'EST', 'Features - EST', 'HD', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', 'Open', 'WSP', '10.5000', '', '', '', '', '10.5240/DD84-FBF4-8F67-D6F3-47FF-1', '10.5240/B091-00D4-8215-39D8-0F33-8', '', '', '', 'U2254', '', '', '1998', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '113811', '', '', '', '', '', 'U2254', '', 'Spanish (LAS)', 'US', '10', 'USA NATL SALE', '2017-05-11 00:00:00', 'TIER 3', '21', '', '', 'USA NATL SALE-SPANISH LANGUAGE', 'SPAN']

]
```

And so I'm looking to be able to state which rows it should load (or skip) and which columns it should skip (usecols). Is that possible to do with an internal python data structure?

Comment: [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) has no such arguments. Did you mean `read_table` or `read_csv`?

Comment: @Parfait I have a list of lists that I'm trying to load into pandas. So would `read_table` work on that?

Comment: We need a fuller code block and input data. [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) reads from a file or buffer.

Comment: @Parfait thanks -- I've updated the question above.

Comment: What is *num_rows*, *skip_rows*, *header_row*, *limit_cols* variables?

Comment: Since you're not using .csv data, you don;t actually have rows or cols to skip. For skipping rows, you can just slice your list, e.g. to skip 10, call the constructor on `self.data[10:]`, and you can slice into each sublist similarly for skip_cols. If you feed `self.data` into a numpy array instead of a list of lists, that gives you more control over multidimensional indexing/slicing

Comment: @Parfait those are what I pass when I use the read_csv module.